# modules with local endomorphism ring over path algebras

Tags: representation-theory

Let $\mathcal{Q}$ be a finite linear quiver (a dynkin quiver of the form $A_n$). Let $R$ be a commutative semisimple ring. Is it true that each $R\mathcal{Q}$-module with local endomorphism ring is indecomposable?

Comment: Isn't every module with local endomorphism ring indecomposable?

Answer (score 1):

As "Lord Shark the Unknown" remarked in the comments, any module (over any ring) with local endomorphism ring is indecomposable. It this essentially due to this fact: *A non-zero module is indecomposable if and only if its endomorphism ring has no nontrivial idempotents.*